# Why can't dynamic linq include first character searching?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq, dynamic-linq-core

I started to use Dynamic LINQ. I don't understand why below code can't include first character of search variable when searching?

```
query = query.Where($"{orderColumn}.Contains(@0)", search);
```

For example;
word: istanbul,
When I search "stanbul", It is okay, it gets. But When I search "istan", it doesn't get.

Could you anyone help me?

Comment: Should work. Are you sure this is not a case-sensitive or encoding issue where the first letter of your word is not a lower case i? See example at https://dotnetfiddle.net/J9cFC5.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, I changed some and it works again. But my locale code is not working correctly. https://dotnetfiddle.net/JuCrYh

Comment: thanks a lot! I reviewed my code and I found why it doesn't work. 
I am making the search variable lowercase before calling :/